# How can I connect two indoor ductless A/C's to one compressor?

Tags: hvac

I have one Hitachi i-clean split AC 2ton unit installed in my home. I want to connect another indoor ductless unit to the already installed outdoor compressor. I only need to use one indoor unit at a time.  How do I connect two indoor units to a single compressor - is this possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible (I've seen it done) though it might help to know the exact model number of the compressor you have to determine if it's possible with this unit. Also I don't really think this is a DIY job unfortunately.

Comment: ya know...for mild climates, this is an option I had never considered...splitting one compressor between two heads with only one used at once. I imagine this would be most doable with some electronic set up where it wouldn't allow both to be run at once.

Comment: I noticed before you're question was edited you said you are going to install .... Unit have you already or just looking? You can buy dual head units made for the specific purpose you want.

Comment: The capacity of the unit is obviously a concern. A compressor designed for one indoor unit is not likely to work as well with two. I know you've said that you are only going to use one at a time, but you should also consider what to do when you resell the house. A home inspection may pick up on that, and a smart buyer will want that to be fixed (either by subtracting money or getting you to buy a new unit).

Comment: I think it is not possible because one room is large then 2nd room so if one room is cold then the compressor is turned of and the other room is not cold

Comment: Solenoid valve and relay protections are okay. Since, 2 similar indoor units will work 1 at a time,
modification of compressor by relieve valve is not necessary.

Comment: Could you please provide feedback on the success of this endeavour. I am planning on going the same route: 1x condenser, 2x evaporators, but using only one room at a time while the other is isolated from the system. Thank you. JJ

Answer (score 3):

If his house is relatively new and well insulated and not too enormous (1500 SF or less) and not in a very hot area, two tons is probably enough for the whole house most of the time. I've got 2.25 tons downstairs and 2.5 tons upstairs in a 3200 SF house and it's always been more than enough so 2 tons for 1500 SF or less is probably fine even if you run both evaporators at once.

However, I would want to be sure that you could switch off one of the two evaporators because that seems essential to his planned usage. It could be for energy savings or just because he already knows 2 tons isn't enough for the entire house, he doesn't say.

The actual question of connecting two evaporators to one condensor is quite easy, you just need to add a T to the freon supply and a T to the freon return. But how will the compressor be told to turn on? You don't want the room with the evaporator you are not using to run the compressor.

And how do you stop freon from going to the evaporator you are not using?

Comment: I agree in the past I have run 2 evaporators in parallel what I found if the units are at different levels or have a large difference in size I needed to add some regulators to balance the loads.

Answer (score 1):

The outdoor unit needs to have a control board that allows for more than on indoor unit to hook to.  At minimal you would need to changed the board unless it already has it in it, which is not common.  Then the system must have separate valves for each indoor unit so to prevent refrigerant flowing to the unit not being used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. If you really do use only 1 at a time, this piping (tee it in where possible) will work. Only 1 terminal will work at a time and the condenser will only see 1 indoor coil (the load).

If you use more than 1 terminal at a time, then it depends if the outdoor unit (outdoor compressor) can meet the demand (indoor coils). A 2-ton outdoor unit will give you a little more than 2-tons when more than 1 terminal unit is operating but there is a limit.

Each manufacturer can be different regarding how to wire in the additional thermostat. Check with a rep to find out the exact Tstat wiring (i.e., the inclusion of another indoor unit) and Tstat programming.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

It can but you must modify the circuit to protect from operating both of them at same time by the following:

- You need to install two T connections at the IN/OUT of compressor.
- Modify the compressor protection by adding relive valve to bypass the pressure upon increasing pressure.
- Use two solenoid valves each one at the O/P T tube which will feed the Indoor unit.

Solenoid valves will be feed power from O/P terminal in indoor unite which assigned to feed out door unit and add relay protection to prevent both solenoid open.

Remember if you are feeding the the two indoor unit from different power source so you must install relay or contractor which will feed the Compressor from independent power source or direct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this idea and you may not go wrong. 
The idea is "Do not try to run both indoor unit simultaneously. This is important in load aspect when we connect two indoor unit to one out door unit ". Secondly we can use a two way switch like what we use two switchs to control one light. In the same logic,  at a time only one indoor unit can be run and you can cool any of one room. 
But trying to run both the indoor unit simultaneously and either of one will definitely cause load mismatch to the compressor and hence not viable.

Answer (score 0):

Just  put a T Valve on the out and Input side of the Freon but at each line after the T Valve, add another Manual Valve that you can personally close or open  when every you  Need to. This will allow you to either use the two unite at a time or just close the other unite manually when you dont Need it.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed this system it works great but with a small problem. I have connected 2 indoor unit with 1 outdoor unit and use 2 T-joints on liquid line and 1 T-joint on return line. With system, 2 danfoss solenoid valves are connected just before the inlet line to the each indoor unit, these valves are protected by contractor relay and connected with power supply to indoor unit. Apart from that i used additional capillary tubes on each inlet line to indoors.

It works great when used one unit at a time.But when two units run simultaneously then there is a cooling difference between them. The one unit cools more, and the other one performance is not satisfactory.